# UPS Shipping Quotes

Tags: shipping, ups

All of sudden this morning, the UPS shipping quotes do not work. The FedEx shipping quotes still come through, but the UPS is now just continually unavailable no matter the destination.

Does anyone know what could cause this out of the blue? Or if UPS has changed anything in their API recently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference;

UPS is upgrading all of their servers to TLS1.2, one by one, and apparently my servers time had come (unfortunately during business hours), after a few hours, the update must've concluded, and all is well again without any changes on my end.